# Using POST in Rest API just like get to add 2 numbers

Tags: rest

I am new to REST and web services. I am trying to add two numbers with the below code.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/calc")
public class CalcREST {

    /*@GET
    @Path("/add/{a}/{b}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String addPlainTextPost(@PathParam("a") double a, @PathParam("b") double b) {
        return (a + b) + "";
    }*/

    @POST
    @Path("/add/{a}/{b}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String addPlainTextPost(@PathParam("a") double a, @PathParam("b") double b) {
        return addPlainText(a,b);
    }

    public String addPlainText(double a, double b) {
        return (a + b) + "";
    }
 }
```

I am trying to test using both GET and POST. For both GET and POST I am invoking the APIs as
http://:9999/calcrest/calc/add/1/5

For Get I get the results properly. However If i comment out GET and keep POST, I am not able to get any results, just blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which tool you use to send POST request? Use debugger to confirm that addPlainTextPost is getting called. If you try to send POST by specifying /add/1/2 in browser - the browser will send GET request, not POST. Use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

Comment: When you are commenting GET,  I assume you still sending the GET request.. Can you tell how are u sending the request

Comment: No offense, but why on earth would you write a REST interface to add two numbers together?

Comment: @jonathan...I asked a simplified version of the actual problem

Comment: @Vineet...I commented GET to test whether I am able to call POST. If I uncomment GET, it gets the match and call happens

Comment: Can you debug server? Do you get to the addPlainTextPost method?

Comment: What status code do you receive in case of POST? is it 200?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are calling this url from a browser and a browser is always going to do a GET on the url. If you want to try POST, you will have to either write a REST client in any one of your preferred languages (javascript, java) or if you are using firefox you can use POSTER plugin to simulate a POST. See here: [POSTER](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/).

Here is a quick REST client example (code snippet) in java. I have used jersey REST client.

```
WebResource webResource = restClient.resource("/calcrest/calc/add");
webResource = webResource.path("1").path("5");

String response = webResource.type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .post(ClientResponse.class);
System.out.println("Your addition: "+response);
```

I hope this helps!